# Logstash Not Recognizing The Lat/Lon fileds in Json Format

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file, logstash-jdbc

I have fields like A_Latitude, A_Longitude, B_Latitude and B_Longitude. I would like to make use of this data and create Maps in Kibana. The problem is data is getting into elasticsearch, but the gejson columns created in Logstash filter not gettin recognized and data is not being fed into geo_point1 and geo_point2.

Hence, first created a geo_point mapping in Kibana dev tools as follows,

```
PUT cc-test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "geo_point1":{
      "type": "geo_point"
       },
      "geo_point2":{
      "type": "geo_point"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I have configured my logstash config file the following way,

```
input {
  jdbc {
   # Postgres jdbc connection string to our database, mydb
      jdbc_connection_string => "some string"
   # The user we wish to execute our statement as
      jdbc_user => "User"
      jdbc_password => "Password"
   # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
      jdbc_driver_library => "/apps/ELK/logstash/driver/ngdbc-2.4.56.jar"
      jdbc_driver_class => "com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver"
   # our query
   #jdbc_validate_connection => true
   #schedule => "* * * * *"
   #record_last_run => true
   # last_run_metadata_path => "login.txt"
     statement => "SELECT
     inputdata.A_LATITUDE, inpudata.A_LONGITUDE, inputdata.B_LATITUDE,
     inputdata.B_LONGITUDE, outputdata.BANDWIDTH, inputdata.SEQUENCEID,
     inputdata.REQUESTTIMESTAMP
     FROM inputdata, outputdata
     WHERE
     inputdata.SEQUENCEID = outputdata.SEQUENCEID
     AND inputdata.REQUEST_TIMESTAMP >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
     AND inputdata.SEQUENCEID IS NOT NULL
     AND inputdata.SEQUENCEID NOT IN ('N/A')
     ORDER BY inputdata.SEQUENCEID DESC "
  # jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
  # jdbc_page_size => "10000"
    }
}

filter {
  mutate {
   convert => { "A_LONGITUDE" => "float" }
   convert => { "A_LATITUDE" => "float" }
   convert => { "B_LONGITUDE" => "float" }
   convert => { "B_LATITUDE" => "float" }
  }
 mutate {
  rename => {
   "A_LONGITUDE" => "[geo_point1][lon]"
   "A_LATITUDE" => "[geo_point1][lat]"
  }
}
mutate {
   rename => {
  "B_LONGITUDE" => "[geo_point2][lon]"
  "B_LATITUDE" => "[geo_point2][lat]"
  }
 }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["http://some server"]
  index => "cc-test"
  #document_type => "system_logs"
  user => "Username"
  password => "Password"
}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Don't understand what is wrong with the Filter part and why data is not getting into the columns geo_point1 and geo_point2!!
Somebody please help :pray::pray::pray:

Comment: Did you put the mapping before creating the index? I was not able to reproduce your issue using your filters and output pipeline with some latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: Hi @leandrojmp I did create the mapping before creating index. The mapping code I've given above.